# nodejs axios socket hang up with increasing payload size

Tags: node.js, rest, sockets, axios, freeze

I have a nodejs rest endpoint that takes a JSON payload and publishes it to a messaging endpoint. As the payload increases, the rest endpoint throws a socket hangup. Same endpoint with a small payload works properly, however, as the payload size increases it throws socket hang up error.

Here is a payload that works:

```
    [{
    "actor": {
      "objectType": "Agent",
      "name": "dubb xtvs2optimized222",
      "mbox": "mailto:apti2+optimized222@test.com"
    },
    "verb": {
      "id": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/verbs/completed",
      "display": {
        "en-US": "completed"
      }
    },
    "object": {
      "objectType": "Activity",
      "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021#/id/60657787eac022769f083c96",
      "definition": {
        "name": {
          "en": "2. Organizational Data"
        },
        "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/media"
      }
    },
    "result": {
      "completion": true
    },
    "context": {
      "extensions": {
        "https://www.example.com/course/name": "xtvs",
        "https://www.example.com/course/version": "7.1",
        "https://www.example.com/course/language": "en",
        "optimized": true
      },
      "contextActivities": {
        "grouping": [
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021",
            "definition": {
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/course",
              "name": {
                "en": " Module 1: Introduction to xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "description": {
                "en": ""
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021#/id/60657783eac022769f083ba0",
            "definition": {
              "name": {
                "en": "1. The World of xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/lesson"
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021",
            "definition": {
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/course",
              "name": {
                "en": " Module 1: Introduction to xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "description": {
                "en": ""
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021#/id/60657783eac022769f083ba0",
            "definition": {
              "name": {
                "en": "1. The World of xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/lesson"
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021",
            "definition": {
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/course",
              "name": {
                "en": " Module 1: Introduction to xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "description": {
                "en": ""
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021#/id/60657783eac022769f083ba0",
            "definition": {
              "name": {
                "en": "1. The World of xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/lesson"
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021",
            "definition": {
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/course",
              "name": {
                "en": " Module 1: Introduction to xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "description": {
                "en": ""
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021#/id/60657783eac022769f083ba0",
            "definition": {
              "name": {
                "en": "1. The World of xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/lesson"
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021",
            "definition": {
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/course",
              "name": {
                "en": " Module 1: Introduction to xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "description": {
                "en": ""
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021#/id/60657783eac022769f083ba0",
            "definition": {
              "name": {
                "en": "1. The World of xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/lesson"
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021",
            "definition": {
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/course",
              "name": {
                "en": " Module 1: Introduction to xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "description": {
                "en": ""
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021#/id/60657783eac022769f083ba0",
            "definition": {
              "name": {
                "en": "1. The World of xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/lesson"
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021",
            "definition": {
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/course",
              "name": {
                "en": " Module 1: Introduction to xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "description": {
                "en": ""
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021#/id/60657783eac022769f083ba0",
            "definition": {
              "name": {
                "en": "1. The World of xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/lesson"
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021",
            "definition": {
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/course",
              "name": {
                "en": " Module 1: Introduction to xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "description": {
                "en": ""
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021#/id/60657783eac022769f083ba0",
            "definition": {
              "name": {
                "en": "1. The World of xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/lesson"
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021",
            "definition": {
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/course",
              "name": {
                "en": " Module 1: Introduction to xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "description": {
                "en": ""
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021#/id/60657783eac022769f083ba0",
            "definition": {
              "name": {
                "en": "1. The World of xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/lesson"
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021",
            "definition": {
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/course",
              "name": {
                "en": " Module 1: Introduction to xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "description": {
                "en": ""
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021#/id/60657783eac022769f083ba0",
            "definition": {
              "name": {
                "en": "1. The World of xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/lesson"
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021",
            "definition": {
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/course",
              "name": {
                "en": " Module 1: Introduction to xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "description": {
                "en": ""
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021#/id/60657783eac022769f083ba0",
            "definition": {
              "name": {
                "en": "1. The World of xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/lesson"
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021",
            "definition": {
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/course",
              "name": {
                "en": " Module 1: Introduction to xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "description": {
                "en": ""
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021#/id/60657783eac022769f083ba0",
            "definition": {
              "name": {
                "en": "1. The World of xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/lesson"
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021",
            "definition": {
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/course",
              "name": {
                "en": " Module 1: Introduction to xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "description": {
                "en": ""
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021#/id/60657783eac022769f083ba0",
            "definition": {
              "name": {
                "en": "1. The World of xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/lesson"
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021",
            "definition": {
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/course",
              "name": {
                "en": " Module 1: Introduction to xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "description": {
                "en": ""
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021#/id/60657783eac022769f083ba0",
            "definition": {
              "name": {
                "en": "1. The World of xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/lesson"
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021",
            "definition": {
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/course",
              "name": {
                "en": " Module 1: Introduction to xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "description": {
                "en": ""
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021#/id/60657783eac022769f083ba0",
            "definition": {
              "name": {
                "en": "1. The World of xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/lesson"
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021",
            "definition": {
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/course",
              "name": {
                "en": " Module 1: Introduction to xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "description": {
                "en": ""
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021#/id/60657783eac022769f083ba0",
            "definition": {
              "name": {
                "en": "1. The World of xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/lesson"
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021",
            "definition": {
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/course",
              "name": {
                "en": " Module 1: Introduction to xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "description": {
                "en": ""
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021#/id/60657783eac022769f083ba0",
            "definition": {
              "name": {
                "en": "1. The World of xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/lesson"
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021",
            "definition": {
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/course",
              "name": {
                "en": " Module 1: Introduction to xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "description": {
                "en": ""
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021#/id/60657783eac022769f083ba0",
            "definition": {
              "name": {
                "en": "1. The World of xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/lesson"
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021",
            "definition": {
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/course",
              "name": {
                "en": " Module 1: Introduction to xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "description": {
                "en": ""
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021#/id/60657783eac022769f083ba0",
            "definition": {
              "name": {
                "en": "1. The World of xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/lesson"
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021",
            "definition": {
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/course",
              "name": {
                "en": " Module 1: Introduction to xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "description": {
                "en": ""
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021#/id/60657783eac022769f083ba0",
            "definition": {
              "name": {
                "en": "1. The World of xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/lesson"
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021",
            "definition": {
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/course",
              "name": {
                "en": " Module 1: Introduction to xrcxssecurity"
              },
              "description": {
                "en": ""
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://test_Module_1_21042021#/id/60657783eac022769f083ba1",
            "definition": {
              "name": {
                "en": "2. Organizational Data"
              },
              "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/lesson"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "id": "bfced0ab-490a-4ffd-ac37-9f8a1719fe4c",
    "timestamp": "2021-07-12T21:59:53.818Z"
  }]
```

If that payload array has up to 6 elements it works properly. however adding more elements to the array throws a socket hang up. I don't see any max content message or max request body errors, any pointers?

Comment: Is the rest endpoint your code or someone else's code?  If it's your code, please show us the code.  If not, then that is apparently just the way it behaves - nothing you can control from the client-side of things.  Either it has some internal limit and you're exceeding it or it encounters some other problem with the payload.  You could run some experiments to see if the failure is based on the number of bytes of the payload or if the failure is based on the number of objects in the largest array.

Comment: It's my code. It's a simple post request axios.post(url, body, {headers: headers, httpAgent: keepaliveAgent}); On a side note, the same request with payload works fine with a php rest endpoint.

Comment: I asked if the ENDPOINT is your code?  That's the receiving side of the request.  That's the code we need to see.

Comment: ah, just to be clear. Nodejs rest end point is kind of a proxy to a kafka rest endpoint(confluent rest proxy). Client requests are handled by nodejs rest end point and after basic validation, sends it to Kafka via a rest call. This is where i see an issue when the client requests come in, and as the payload size increases, nodejs rest end point throws a socket hang up error, however it is able to push it to the same kafka rest end point successfully with smaller payloads.

Comment: OK, none of that was clear in your question.  Please edit your question to make that clear.  And, please post whatever relevant code you control.  Now that you mention there's a proxy involved, this sounds like a problem with the proxy.  We can't help without seeing relevant code.  I'm going to bow out of this conversation now since I can't guess what your code is and can't guess the architecture for the request either.